# How to refresh fragment activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I need to REFRESH Fragment Activity on button click,i am trying to implement multiple theme.

Suggestions appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simply recreate the entire Activity?
Try the following in onButtonClick:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Answer (score 0):

just define a method in the **fragment interface** and call it to replace the current fragment with **new instance of same fragment**.